# Create Custom PHP page for Wordpress that doesnt require a page in the DB

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a multi-site setup and i want to add a global user profile page to all sites. Based on advice i was given i used a page template. I have created a file called myprofile.php and in here it does all the magic to create a page. The problem i have with this is that i must create a page within the WordPress admin panel that uses this template.

With multiple sites on the network I don't want the risk of someone deleting the page from the list or forgetting to add it etc and it causes a bunch of 404 errors, denying users basic functionality.

I want to be able to add a page to my entire WordPress install, including all multi-sites. It needs to be able to do everything that my page template does, but doesn't require a Page to exist in the page listing.

I tried doing this using a php file and using mod_rewrite, calling the WordPress header and footer and this worked, but its returning a 404 error even though the page content is displaying. I was able to manually set the header to 200 using php, but this isn't being picked up by all header scans that i have performed and its not a solution i am particularly happy with. I would like to build this into WordPress rather than making it separate and calling WordPress externally.

Can this be done?

Edit. 
In needing a profile page i will also need a login, view other user profile page, change account settings and any other error/account related pages that come with a user profile, so having to create a dozen custom pages for every multi-site is going to be very annoying and messy.

I am also not using the WordPress user database for this as I use the user accounts for various other things outside of WordPress.

Comment: Is the graphic theme always the same ? In that case you could call that page from a link the header or in the footer

Comment: well i want to be able to integrate it in with the theme by calling the header and footer to wrap around the profile page so it will fit the look and feel of the theme selected. Doing this without the 404 error is the main issue as this seems quite messy

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58683/how-to-create-a-front-end-user-profile-with-a-friendly-permalink

Comment: I should also add that i dont want to use the wordpress user system as there is a lot of custom features i need to use and i also use this user DB outside of wordpress